# DataView.ListChanged event is not fired when adding rows to source table

Tags: c#, dataview, listchanged

In some cases when i add a new row to a table, it doesn't fire the ListChanged event.
the strange thing is that updating and removing rows does fire the event.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually invoke the ListChanged event.
But until i see some code, i cannot give you a more direct answer.